# Magento XML Block Qualities

Tags: xml, magento

I don't know what you call these different kinds of blocks but I need to make this block:

```
   <block type="poll/poll" name="enquete2" template="poll/poll.phtml">
    <action method="setPollId">
      <poll_id>2</poll_id>
    </action>
    </block>
```

...into one of these kinds of blocks:

```
{{block type="poll/poll" name="poll_one" template="poll/poll.phtml" poll_id="1"}}
```

I've got the first part but can the **action part** be also added? The problem I'm having is I'm wanting to add this to a CMS Block in magento then add it to a Widget Block that way I can control where it get put into the layout.

thanks

Comment: Why not create this XML in the CMS Layout settings from magento backend? Backend->CMS->Choose cms->Design

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/placing-a-block-in-a-cms-page-sidebar <- Reference

Comment: I tried to help with the issue, but failed to understand, what is asked. Seems like one question is asked in the description, the other is asked in answer, there are some different comments, etc. I propose to delete everything you don't need to know, delete that "pseudo" answer and put the only one clear question to the description. Otherwise is is really hard to comprehend, what should be solved.

Comment: My problems are multifaceted ...for sure! hahaha. Really thou, I'm just trying to have more than one poll on my website. I have it working to a point. Just enough to bug me. With the XML and poll.phtml I have posted here my polls show up and you can vote. But the results stay on the page even after you refresh the page or change pages. The correct way it is suppose to work is that the poll is suppose to not show after one page view. I don't know hoe else to explain it? But any help on this critical issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not Really an answer but I needed more room.

Yes, that works. Actually it seems both ways work. The problem is that the poll results stay after one votes and refreshes the page.

I'm using this code in poll.phtml:

```
<?php
$pollActive = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("poll/activePoll"); 
if ($this->poll_id) {
$pollActive->setPollId($this->poll_id);
$pollActive->setPollTemplate('poll/active.phtml', 'poll');
$pollActive->setPollTemplate('poll/result.phtml', 'results');
} 
echo $pollActive->toHtml();
?>
```

I got from here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-frontend/reusing-magento-poll-on-any-page-or-any-block/

I don't know how to get the poll to disappear like the Magento default poll does after the vote is made. I thought it had to do with my XML.

Comment: It think, that you are right the vote results block is show only once after the vote ... I think, that it's odd!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I could put something like, "if {$PollBeenVotedAlready} echo "don't show"; else "show'} hahaha Got any code for that?